# Получить переменную за пределами цикла python

Tags: python

```
a=0
b=1
while True:

    if a<b:
        a=4

print(a)
```

Как получить значение а=4 вне цикла?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь ничего не мешает получить это значение, кроме бесконечного цикла. Остановите его при нужном случае.

```
a=0
b=1
while True:
    if a<b:
        a=4
        break

print(a)
```

Если же проблема более глобальна и пример просто неудачный, то, вероятно, следует смотреть в сторону `yield`

Comment: да, пример вообще корявый получился.

Comment: Ну так можно прояснить, что имелось в виду. Или yield подошёл?

Comment: использовал global a

Answer (score 1):

Если вы вводите новую переменную внутри цикла, главная её особенность то, что она перезаписывается при итерации:

```
for w in [1, 2, 3]:
    print w
print w
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 3
```

Заметьте, что в пространстве переменных после окончания цикла `w` приняла и сохранила значение `3` для дальнейших команд.

Хорошей практикой является не использование переменных из цикла, а объявление их перед ним с последующим присвоением:

```
w = None
b = 1
for a in [0, 1]:
    if a < b:
        w = 4
        break
print w
# 4
```

Плюс писать в условие для `while` просто `True` мне кажется не true - получается некоторый провал в логике программы - можно использовать обычный цикл или без него. Пример условия if else в одну строку:

```
a = 0
b = 1
w = 4 if a < b else None
print w
# 4
```